# Azure App Service : Custom Authentication & Social providers

Tags: authentication, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing with Azure Mobile App service, and wondering if custom authentication and available authentication/authorization can co-exist.

Meaning I can allow my user to login either using Google/Microsoft/FB/etc. or have a local login user database to register.

I saw number of articles on using custom authentication - but will it work if I enable the other services in Azure as well :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make custom and provided authentication co-exist.  For details, see chapter 2 of the ZUMO Book at http://aka.ms/zumobook